# Rails: Generate URL without parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, for-loop, routes

For example I have simple routes like:

```
get 'something/:param' => 'controller#action'
```

Request path in this case is `/something/123` for example

Being in controller how to generate URL w/o parameter(s) like `/something` using Rails features?

Other examples:

```
get 'something/:param/action' => 'controller#action': '/something/action'  
get 'something/:param/:param2' => 'controller#action': '/something'
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this? You just get rid of the :param.

```
get 'something/' => 'controller#action'
get 'something/action' => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: No, I mean how to generate URL without any parameters being in controller action. In controller action I have request path '/something/123' and I want to get '/something' without '123'. And this is should be universal code for any url/route. Route itself remains unchanged.

Comment: try this 
get 'something(/:param)' => 'application#test'  - param wil be optional

Comment: The question is not about how to change my routes :) I just want to generate some kind of unusual URLs :) May be my Eng is not good enough.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Im thinking he want to still pass the parameter in the request, but hide it in the url. There are some workarounds to this that Ive seen, give me a minute

Comment: There's no workaround, you either use the rails way as described, pass it as a POST var or a normal GET var.

Comment: @bo-oz: I have an URL string like '/something/:param/action' and want to REMOVE param to get '/something/action'. Not to obscure or protect, but just to get another URL string without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to protect or obscure the ids in the routes, or simply have nicer looking urls, then you might want to try the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.